# Which way I should choose for aws s3 bucket my website project by using nuxtjs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

i really confused about using **ssr or spa** to my website. I'm planing publish on **s3 bucket by static**.

So my first quesiton is do i need nodejs or not for ssr on s3 bucket?

Second question is nuxtjs is using ssr for i know but and see on opitons 'spa'. Just I'dont understand i can use spa with vuejs why i need nuxtjs for spa?

Last question is when i choose the spa on options, see two options more.

*>Server (Node.js hosting)

*>Static (Static/Jamstack hosting)

and I notice on ssr mode these two options avaible there. So I can publish my nuxt project with ssr but static?

[image: Screenshoot]

I really need your help people. Thanks

Comment: S3 is only for static apps. A Single Page Application can be either static or use Server Side Rendering. You don't need and can't use node.js with S3 static apps.

Comment: A lot of questions here. Let's take it step by step and think about the platform later. Do you need SSR for your app? What are the benefits of SSR over a simple SPA? If you don't need SSR, Nuxt may not be the best way to go. Then, looking at the limitations and what you want to do, we could either recommend `static` or `server` indeed. Nuxt will give you a lot of tooling actually, meaning that even if you go SPA, you could benefits from it's structure and make something cool. But I'd rather recommend [vitesse](https://github.com/antfu/vitesse) if you want Vue3 + SPA + cool tooling!

Comment: Thank you for helps guys. I choose the  Universal (SSR / SSG) + Static (Static/Jamstack hosting)

Comment: Alright, then you can probably host it on Netlify or Vercel.